# How can I manually measure the life expectancy of a SSD?

Tags: macos, ssd, storage

How could I calculate the average `read/write cycles` per day/month/year of a SSD and then include factors for `x` controller or `y` and `z` components. I have a 500 GB SSD on a MBA running OS X 10.8.5.

I checked different sources online but couldn't find a method.

Answer (score 0):

Compare to your warranty's fine print on allowed writes. To compute writes over time get your power-on hours from any SMART tool and divide total writes (usually also visible in SMART) by that. Then it's just a matter of computing how far you are from that warranty number. Modern SSDs are very reliable so it is abnormal to see failure before max warrantied writes.

Most (Samsung 850 Pro esp) will happily run way past, but the manufacturers want to sell barely-better $5,000+ versions for servers (some of which are literally the same storage chips and drive controllers, just replicated behind an internal RAID-1), and discourage RAID-10ing top-end consumer Samsung / Intel / Crucial drives for 1/5 the cost.

Nobody really tracks read since it's more or less harmless, so you're SOL using that as a failure predictor.

Comment: Nice answer, technically - but I do think in real-world terms, you'd be just as well to mark some random date on a calendar… or even just consult the tarot or chicken-bones. Mean time to failure is just that, some electronics live waay past that, some die in the first week.

Comment: Right, but few die in between. Failure is installation and EOL-loaded. Overwhelming majority of drives that make it past a month will make it to their MTBF. At least that was true for HDDs.

Comment: All I'm saying is "you can never know" & it's fairly pointless drawing up your replacement/disaster strategy on that.

Comment: @Tetsujin: so what you're saying is basically any life expectancy estimation is meaningless? I'd agree in principle - you never know when drive will fail - but on the other hand many tests suggest that SSDs "do not go quietly int the night". They usually exceed MFR's life expectancy and usually give ample warning. and, also, one tend to be way earlier than the other. Or, to be prcise: former extremely before latter.

Comment: I think that you believe I'm attacking your answer; whereas in fact I'm supporting it - with the proviso that however you work the numbers, you still never know. Let me take an *extreme* example… would you only begin to backup the drive in the month before the MTBF?

Comment: Ah, i don't. That was a different user. I always use a redundant RAID level and image backups of the OS & VM partitions.

Comment: @ArthurKay - so sorry, I didn't spot that. My bad >.<

Comment: @ArthurKay, how do I get the fine print of a built-in part? Could you provide an example related to my system? I guess I could get `smartmontools` and do `Total_LBAs_Written` / `Power_On_Hours`. I'll install it and see if I can somehow get the allowed writes.

Comment: Ahhhh, surface pro or similar? Interesting. What model ssd is that?

Comment: The drive model is `APPLE SSD SM512E`, so I guess Samsung's, and `smartmontools` list a huge raw `Wear_Leveling_Count`, but that needs some interpreting